# How to get mount point from USB connected device

Tags: android, filesystems, usb

I'm working on application that must detect connected Mass storage devices and provide access to their files(as a native filesystem)
Using UsbDeviceManager, I get UsbDeviceConnection(2 endpoints to read and write bites from/to usb device), but I was could not find a way how get usb flash drive mount point, or if filesystem don't mount it, mount it and use.
Filesystems: FAT/ exFAT

Comment: Thank you, but there is no answer how to get it. I tryed it using NDK, but it did not help me